# Why java cannot initialize object with null?

Tags: java

I have a question about java fundamental.
java can assign parameter value with null
but why java cannot Initialize Object with null?
can Someone explain that.

```
// this will be fine.
String data = null ;

String data2 = null;

// Compiler still fine but Exception when execute. 
data = new String(data);

// Cannot Compile 
data = new String(null);
```

the reason is :I want to  check null parameter from Constructor but not need to declare useless parameter like below :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SomeObject data = new SomeObject("a",null,"b",null,"c",null);
}  

public class SomeObject{
    public SomeObject(String... x) {
        for(int i=1 ; i<x.length;i++){
            if(x[i]==null){
                System.err.println("Something");
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: null means you have no object, so how can you say you want a new object with no object?

Comment: May I know what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz I want to test my constructor with no declare  unless parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because `null` is untyped. In your last assignment, the compiler cannot determine which constructor to use. With the following code:

```
data = new String((String)null);
```

you would not have a compilation error (but of course, an exception at run time).

Answer (score 0):

When you init a String object with a param, the constructor will take hash and value properties of this param. If the param is null, it will cause NullException.

This is from JavaDoc.

```
 /**
 * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
 * the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the
 * newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an
 * explicit copy of {@code original} is needed, use of this constructor is
 * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
 *
 * @param  original
 *         A {@code String}
 */
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> String data = null ;

This means *"make variable `data` point to nothing"*. That is totally fine both compile and runtime.

> data = new String(otherData);

This means *"make variable `data` point to new `String` object created by copying the data from existing `otherData` object of type `String`"*. This is totally fine compile time as there is no way for the compiler to know what `otherData` will be pointing to at runtime. However if at runtime `otherData` is `null` *(points to nothing)* there is no way to copy the data from nothing and thus it throws an Exception

> data = new String(null);

This means *"make variable `data` point to new `String` object created by copying the data from nothing*. In this case the compiler does not know which constructor to use because it can't guess the type of the argument from nothing which results in compilation error.

> data = new String((String)null);

This means *"make variable `data` point to new `String` object created by copying the data from nothing of type `String`*. In this case the compiler knows which constructor to use because of the type of the argument and there will be no compilation error. However at runtime the `String(String original)` constructor will not be able to copy from nothing and will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. Compilation on `new String(null)` actually fails due to ambiguity.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, you are right, I was just updating it. I tried to simplify things and it end up being incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that Java can't initialise an Object with `null`, it just can't call a `String(...)` constructor with `null`.

```
// this will be fine.
String data = null;
String data2 = null;
```

> In fact at this point you have already initialised the variables data and data2, both to `null`.

```
// Compiler still fine but Exception when execute. 
data = new String(data);
```

> This compiles, because the type of `data` is known at compile time (String), and the constructor `String(String)` exists.
>   It fails at runtime, because the code within that constructor expects the argument to be non-null. Because you are passing `null` into it, you will therefore be faced with a `NullPointerException` (NPE).

```
// Cannot Compile 
data = new String(null);
```

> This cannot compile, because `null` is untyped, so the compiler does not know which of the constructors to link. Should it be `String(Integer)`? Adding an explicit cast to tell the compiler the type will work, for example `new String((String)type)`.

---

The crux of the matter is that constructors are in fact no different from any other method invocation in that you can pass any argument (including null) and expect it to do its job. If it's job includes checking for null and dealing with that gracefully, you won't have a problem. But if the constructor's code tries to dereference `null` that was passed in, that will result in an NPE.

Case in point, your code deals with null arguments in the array and should compile and run without any issues, have you tried it?

However, for comparison:

```
new SomeObject(null);           //1) ambiguous
new SomeObject((String[])null); //2) compiles ok, but NPE
new SomeObject((String)null);   //3) ok
```

> **1)** This is ambigous, because you can't be sure whether the array 'x' is null, or the array 'x' is meant to contain a single element of `null`. It is likely that the compiler will allow it and warn only, but being explicit with a cast would be better.
>
> **2)** The explicit cast means the array 'x' will be `null`. This will compile, but you will get an NPE at runtime, since dereferencing `x.length` would be equivalent to attempting `null.length` - a definitive error.
>       new SomeObject(String)
>
> **3)** This is safe, because you are really passing in the array `x = [null]`